# Laravel join two tables using model

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a laravel application in which I want to join two tables and get the result. I have two models, first one is category.php which is given below.

```
class Category extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'product_category_id');
    }



}
```

Second one is products.php

```
class Products extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'product_category_id');
    }

}
```

Now when I write the query `Category::where('status', 1)->get()` it is giving the result. But when I try to join the tables using `Category::find(1)->products()->where('status', 1)->get();` it is giving null result. Please help

Comment: `product_category_id` is on your `categories` table correct?

Comment: @user3158900   Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get products relation and filter the results is:

```
Category::where('status', 1)->with(['products' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('name', 'like', '%search_string%');
}])->get();
```

Comment: How can I add another condition? I want to search products by name

Comment: All of the categories are always coming regardless of the search query. I want a join so that categories with matching search results should come.

Comment: What are you trying to search?

Comment: `...function ($query) use ($search_string) {...`

Comment: That's because when you eager load, that's what it does is get all the categories.  You probably need to use `whereHas` and it doesn't take an array so just remove the square brackets.

Comment: @user315890011 Can you please write the full query

Comment: @Everton.      I want to get the categories that link to the product search

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Search products that matches query string - and get category for each result. Answer is based on your correspondence with Everton's answer.

```
Products::where('name', 'like', '%search_string%')->with(['category' => function ($category) {
    $category->where('status', 1);
}])->get();
```

Change relationship:

```
class Products extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{    
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Category', 'product_category_id');
    }

}
```